# Samba server doesn't show up in Finder on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: mac, finder, samba, osx-lion

I've a Samba server running (version 3.5.8; Linux box), but after upgrading to Mac OS X Lion the Samba server doesn't show up in the "Shared" section in the Finder sidebar anymore. Regular Windows machines show up, so auto-discovery is working. Also I can manually connect to the server (using "Go" -> "Connect to Server" and there entering the server's name), so a connection is possible.

Has anyone got Samba working with Mac OS X Lion?

I noticed that my server and other Windows boxes have different icons. So I clicked on "All..." in the "Shared" section and it looks like this:

[image]

So, here "coppermine-int" is a Windows 7 box, "ite" is a Windows XP box, and "deepthouht" is the Samba server. I used Cmd+I on everyone and it turns out that the Windows boxes have "Kind: PC" but the Samba server has "Kind: Server". That's why they have different icons (and are handled differently, I guess), but this doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Apple switched to their own implementation of samba in Lion, which doesn't like using Bonjour advertised services on port 139 instead preferring 445.

See this [post](http://lime-technology.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=6a6695097f4782fa1ac0f2de7d56011f&topic=14623.msg138068#msg138068) for changes to make to avahi configuration.

Essentially, you will need to edit or create /etc/avahi/services/smb.service

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone='no'?><!--*-nxml-*-->
<!DOCTYPE service-group SYSTEM "avahi-service.dtd">

<service-group>
    <name replace-wildcards="yes">%h-SMB</name>
    <service>
        <type>_smb._tcp</type>
        <port>445</port>
    </service>
    <service>
         <type>_device-info._tcp</type>
         <port>0</port>
         <txt-record>model=Xserve</txt-record>
    </service>
</service-group>
```

Comment: Once I switch the port in the smb.conf file to 445 `smb ports = 445 139`, can I hide the actual samba share so that only Bonjour (avahi) is shown in Finder?

Answer (score 0):

Connect with command-k (which you said you could do)

Once the server is connected look at in the sidebar and change/modify the bonjour name of it to be "more simple". Lion is currently having a lot of issues with SMB shares that have characters in them.

I had a server that had a period(.) in it and was having this exact issue. Changed it to all lowercase letters and it has been splendid ever since.

Comment: That's not it. My server is called "deepthought", so there's no special character in it. In fact, I have a Windows box that's called "coppermine-int" and it shows up (see screenshot in the original post).